# Why I can't get element by ref in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to get the element height via ref using React JS, but without success.

I have something like this :

```
render() {
    let cars = carData.filterCars(this.props.carsToShow, this.props.filters);
    return (
        <div>
            <div className="carList">
                <div className="cars" ref="cars">
                    {cars.map((car, i) => {
                        let carRef = "car-" + car.id;
                        return (
                           <div ref={carRef} key={i}>
                               <div>
                                   <div><img src={car.image_url} /></div>
                                   <div className="carNameAndDesc">
                                        <div>{car.make} {car.model}</div>
                                        <div>{car.price}</div>
                                   </div>
                               </div>
                             </div>
                         );
                      })}
                 </div>
            </div>

            <div ref="bigScreenDetails" className="bigScreenDetails">
               <div className="carDetailsBigScreen">
                    <CarDetails carID={this.state.carID}/>
               </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

And in componentDidMount I try to do it as follows :

```
componentDidMount(){
    let carRef = "car-" + this.props.carID;  //22
    let refs = this.refs[carRef].offsetHeight; //undefined
    let refs1 = this.refs["cars"].offsetHeight; //900
    let refs2 = this.refs["bigScreenDetails"].offsetHeight; //1400
}
```

I can't get ref of the div inside map. Only for that ref I get undefined, for other refs I get the right values.

Any ideas?

console.log(carRef) inside render returns

```
"car-20"
"car-21"
"car-22"
.......
"car-35"
```

And console.log(carRef) inside componentDidMount returns

```
"car-22"
```

But if I `console.log(this.refs)` in componentDidMount I get :

[image]

Thus only two refs insted of three.

**UPDATE**

As if there is absolutely no ref inside

```
{cars.map((car, i) => {
                    let carRef = "car-" + car.id;
                    return (
                       <div ref={carRef} key={i}>

                         </div>
                     );
                  })}
```

Here is the console log :

```
let carRef = "car-" + carID;
    let refs = this.refs;
    let one = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs[carRef]);
    let two = this.carRefs;

    console.log("All refs : " + refs);
    console.log("Vikramaditya : " + one);
    console.log("Tom : " + two);
```

In first console.log I should see all three refs, but I see only two of them.

[image]

Comment: is your car.id coming from db? This could mean that it is an int and not a string, which means that this.refs[carRef] is actually returning this: 'car' 22

Comment: @usedToBeFat I checked it. It is `"car-22"`.

Comment: In your render method let carRef = "car-" + car.id; can you log this carRef and see what it returns?

Comment: I updated my question.

Answer (score 3):

Ideally, avoid using refs in the first place...

If you *need* to use them for some reason, I'd recommend using the callback style. This will allow you to use references to the elements themselves, rather than messing around with strings.

Looking at [the docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html), I'm not even sure whether string refs are supported any more...

If I were you (and I was definitely sure I needed all these refs) I'd do something like this:

```
cars.map(car => (
    <div ref={ref => this.carRefs[car.id] = ref} key={car.id}>
    </div>
))
```

In your constructor, you can assign `this.carRefs = {};`.

Now you can access your cars in the `this.carRefs` object from inside `componentDidMount`.

```js
class TestComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
      super();
      this.carRefs = {};
    }

    componentDidMount() {
      console.log(this.carRefs);
    }

    render() {
        return (<div>
          {this.props.cars.map(({id}) =>
            <div key={id} ref={ref => this.carRefs[id] = ref}></div>)}
        </div>);
    }
}
        
const cars = [{id: 1}, {id: 2}];
ReactDOM.render(<TestComponent cars={cars} /> , document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: What I'm trying to do is to get the offsetTop of the div with that ref. Is there any better way to do it? I have an slider in the parent component with the car photos, and I pass the car id to this child component onClick event. And then in the child component I want to get offsetTop of the car with that id to be able to scroll to it if component is mounted.

Comment: If you need to get the position of the DOM elements, then that sounds like a valid use for refs.

Comment: Yes, I need it to get the position of the elements. I'm going to try your solution.

Comment: We should follow what @TomFenech suggested, but if you still want to use the old way, u can use ```ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs[carRef]).offsetHeight;```.

Comment: @Vikramaditya The problem is that I can't get the ref of the div inside the cars.map(). It's as it doesn't exist at all. The same problem is for the Tom Fenech solution. I've updated my question.

Comment: @Boky I've added a working example to my answer - hope that helps.